# For/in loop not working in service function AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, object, for-loop, service

I have a problem with a for/in inside a function that does not work.

```
$scope.files = [];

jobslisting.getJobs(function(data){

     for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
         $scope.files.push({name:data[i]});
     }

     console.log(data);        
     console.log($scope.files);

});
```

console.log(data) returns:

```
Object {2: "item1", 3: "item2", 4: "item3", 5: "item4", 6: "item5", 7: "item6", 8: "item7", 9: "item8"}
```

console.log($scope.files) returns

```
[]
```

Thanks in advance for any advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your `for` loop never runs, because you are calling `.length` on an object and not on an array.

Instead, replace your `for` loop with `angular.forEach()`, like this:

```
angular.forEach(data, function(val, key) {
    $scope.files.push({name: val});
});
```

More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Answer (score 1):

It looks like data is not an Array, but an object with numbers as the keys. I would check to make absolutely sure wherever you call the service from is sending in an Array. It might also be wise to use an iterator method for data, so it will work with arrays or objects. For that you can roll your own method, or use one that is built into [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/).